Connection to "process /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs" has been closed unexpectedly. with smtp and laravel
"I tried to send emails with SMTP,Laravel version 9 using Gmail and Outlook, but I keep getting always this error: 'Connection to "process /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs" has been closed unexpectedly.'"
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable; use
Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue; use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels; use
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class DiagnosticMail extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $Data = [];

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $Data
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $Data)
    {
        $this->Data = $Data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $data = [
            'subject' => 'Envoyer un email de test',
            'body' => 'hello this is my mail'
        
        ];
    
        return $this->view('scanners.emails')
                    ->with($data)
                    ->to('helahela@gmail.com', 'Destinataire')
                    ->subject('first mail');
    } }


Share your code what you have written

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=helahela@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=helahela@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
